# How to call WCF Service using JQuery $.ajax in Windows Phone 8 (Cordova Application) Phonegap based

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

Please send some sample code & Steps for Calling WCF Service using JQuery $.ajax in Windows Phone 8 (Cordova Application) Phonegap based

Answer (score 0):

Any request out of Apps is cross domain. Calling WCF Service is also consider cross domain.

Before call web service you should check config.xml file for permission to access web service. For access any url.

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
```

For access google and subdomain

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://google.com" />
```

Using Normal JAVASCRIPT:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var seconds = new Date().getTime(); // avoid cache problem
var additionalParam = ""  // if any 
var URL = "http://www.domainname.com/api/method/"; // your URL
var authURL = URL+ additionalParam+'&tmp=' + seconds;
ajax.open("GET", authURL + '', false);
ajax.send();
if (ajax.readyState == 4 && (ajax.status == 200)) {
    console.log("ajax.responseText" + ajax.responseText);
}
```

Using JQuery - $.getJSON();

```
var URL = "http://www.domainname.com/api/method/"; // your URL
var param = {} // if any 
$.getJSON(URL + "?callback=?", param).done(function (responseValue) {
    console.log(responseVal)
}).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    console.log('Error')
});
```

**"?callback=?"** -- For jsonp need to put callback because response gets only callback not direct way

For best approach you can $.getJSON. This is mainly for accessing cross domain.

If you want to refer more about [JSONP Web service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP)

Comment: I am using Phonegap 1.3.0 Js and windows 8 SDK, I am unable call the services, so i need to implement <access subdomains="true" uri="*" /> in Config.xml file, but i didn't find the Config.xml file in my Phonegap project, where should i provide the the Domain Access Permission.